# Value animation supported down to android api 8

Tags: android, animation

I have a RelativeView where I want to animate the heiht of it but I can't figure out how to do it when I need to support down to api 8 (android 2.2).

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

BR
FireFly3000

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to this lib: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids

That will do the trick ;-)